# PHP xpath not able to find child node but finds parent

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am able to load an XML document and create a SimpleXMLElement - I am also able to query it using XPATH but I am perplexed by the behavior I am noticing. When I load the XML and create a SimpleXMLElement - it is of the below structure

XML is as below

```
 <StructuredXMLResume>
        <ContactInfo>
            <PersonName>
                <FullName>Tom Jones</FullName>
                <GivenName>Tom</GivenName>
                <MiddleName />
                <FamilyName>Jones</FamilyName>
            </PersonName>
       </ContactInfo>
 </StructuredXMLResume>


[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [PersonName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [FullName] => Tom Jones
                    [GivenName] => Tom
                    [MiddleName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [FamilyName] => Jones
                )
```

When I execute `$xml->xpath('//PersonName')` I get the right result which is as below

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [FullName] => Tom Jones
            [GivenName] => Tom
            [MiddleName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [FamilyName] => Jones
        )
```

But when I execute `$xml->xpath('//GivenName')` I get the below result - which I am unable to understand

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )
```

Can someone please help me understand what my error is?

Comment: Please show us the XML source, not the SimpleXMLElement debug. Here is a lot of information missing.

Comment: Added the XML file as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like it's working as expected. [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) returns an array of `SimpleXMLElement`s, and you are getting an array with one `SimpleXMLElement` in it.

Have you tried this:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//GivenName');
echo $nodes[0];  // should output:  Tom
// or if that doesn't work, try:
echo (string)$nodes[0];
```

Comment: This outputs `SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [FullName] => Tom Jones
    [GivenName] => Tom
    [MiddleName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [FamilyName] => Jones
)`

Comment: I agree that the array is empty - but how do I access the single element I need?

Comment: @ChicagoSky The array is not empty. It has one element in it, like I said. I meant to use '//GivenName' in my example above. Can you try that?

Comment: It worked - thanks - so if I understand the situation correctly - when I search for a specific unique element, I get an array with a single row. But help me understand why when I am unable to see the value contained when I say print_r($node) but I see the value when I say print_r($node[0])

Comment: XPath location paths always return a list of nodes and SimpleXML returns that list of nodes as an array. It does not change the variable type depending on the element count. And '//GivenName' returns any element node with that name anywhere in the document. It could be none or several (from a technical view).